# Flex box with 1 item twice the size of other items, but still keep everything inline like a grid system

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Ive got a `flexbox` layout that has all the items the same size, apart from one which is twice the width of the other items, but the same height.

The issue im having at the moment is that the top row of the flexbox items are not lining up with the rest of the rows in the flexbox which all contain items of the same width.

Ive made a jsfiddle of the issue here : http://jsfiddle.net/4e8c0w9z/

Any idea if this can be achevied ? I was looking at grid system, but they all seem to work around a fixed number of columns per grid, with break points. Rather than a flexbox which allows for any number of items per row.

Comment: How are you expecting them to line up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel you have a little mathematically problem here. Your `.box2` is not exactly twice as big as `.box`. Even though you use `box-sizing: border-box;` you have to keep in mind the `margin` of the items if you want the gaps to line up properly. Here is a demo of what is happening, when you set the width of `.box2` to 180px (150 + 15 + 15)

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    background: #336633;
}
.wrapper {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    width: 75px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 15px;
    
}

.box2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <!--THIS IS THE 2 width box-->
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

Here is a little addition from @JoshBurgess to make it a little bit more `flex`ible. With this you don't set a specific width but make use of the [`flex-basis property`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/).

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:100%;
    background: #336633;
}
.wrapper {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    flex: 0 1 75px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 15px;
    
}

.box2 {
    flex: 0 1 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <!--THIS IS THE 2 width box-->
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<!--wrapper-->
```

Comment: Can I recommend a `flex` property here as well rather than `width`?  I mean, that's the point of a flexbox, right?  Rule should really be `flex: 1 1 75px` for `.box` and `flex: 2 1 180px` for `.box2`

Comment: @JoshBurgess Actually I think I disagree with you there. Considering how sam has defined the widths already, there is no need to use flexbox. In addition to this, flexbox is not as compatible. There's very little gain and many consequences of using flexbox here.

Comment: definitely @JoshBurgess . But i think the result would be the same in this case. As the dimensions have been given. But a little touch of magic is always nice, so the answer was updated. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Nico O -Your answer dose indeed fix the issue, unfortunately ive noticed an error in the code provided in the JSfiddle, i had this setup on a large display, using wider .box elements, which i then made smaller for the JSfiddle. Unfortunately i didnt calculate the .box2 element correctly when updating code. The setup i had required the `justify-content:space-around;` so that the tiles went full width of their parent div and didnt leave a space down one side. Thats were the difficulty is as i cant hard key a width for the .box2 because of the margin using `justify-content:space-around;`

Comment: So basically you don't have any fixed widths and want the elements to fill the screen until the row is full, but the max-size of each item may be the size of a `.box2`?

Answer (score 0):

I see the first item of the flex box's width is double. But what if the width and height both are double than others. how to solve that  ?